# You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function using click event conditional rendering

Tags: vuejs2

I am rendering two texts based on a condition and be able to pass methods to the click event based on the condition. The default text is ADD TO COLLECTION because initially hasPaid property is false. Once payment has been made, I want to set that property to true

The function addToCollection first opens a modal, on the modal, the handlePayment function is implemented. I have been able to conditionally render the div to show either ADD TO COLLECTION or DOWNLOAD using v-on="". I also return hasPaid property from the handlePayment function.

```
<div class="float-right peexo-faded-text card-inner-text"  :face="face" v-on="!hasPaid ? {click: addToCollection} : {click: handleDownload(face)}">
                                       {{!hasPaid ? 'ADD TO COLLECTION': 'DOWNLOAD' }}
                                    </div>


 data: function () {
            return {
                hasPaid: false,
            }
},
addToCollection(){
                this.showcollectionModal = true;
            },
            handlePayment(){
                this.showcollectionModal = false;
                let accept = true;
                this.showpaymentsuccessmodal = true;
                //this.hasPaid = true;

                return {
                    hasPaid: accept
                }

            },
```

I want to be able to set hasPaid property on the handlePayment function for the render function to pick it, so that the handleDownload function can then work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last section of this bit is going to be problematic:

```
v-on="!hasPaid ? {click: addToCollection} : {click: handleDownload(face)}"
```

When `hasPaid` is `true` it will invoke the method `handleDownload` immediately. That is, it will be called during render, not when the `<div>` is clicked.

You could fix it by 'wrapping' it in a function:

```js
{click: () => handleDownload(face)}
```

I've used an arrow function in my example but you could use a normal function if you prefer.

Personally I wouldn't try to do this using the object form of `v-on`.

My first instinct is that you should consider just having two `<div>` elements and use `v-if` to decide which one is showing.

If you did want to use a single `<div>` I would put the click logic in a method. So:

```html
<div class="..." :face="face" @click="onDivClick(face)">
```

Note that despite the apparent syntactic similarity to the way you defined your click listener this won't invoke the method immediately.

Then in the methods for the component:

```js
methods: {
  onDivClick (face) {
    if (this.hasPaid) {
      this.handleDownload(face)
    } else {
      this.addToCollection()
    }
  }
}
```